# Sorting post by vote counts in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

how can I sort posts by vote counts in Laravel? If I have this kind of tables:

posts table

`id, post_name, post_description`

votes table

`id, post_id, user_id`

I want to sort posts by most votes.

Comment: Use `joins` for this, it will work best.

Answer (score 1):

If you declared your relationships correctly, i guess sth. like that should work:

```
$sortedposts= Post::with('votes')->get()->sortBy(function($post)
{
    return $post->votes->count();
});
```

Comment: There's `get()` missing before the `sortBy`